# Intent from MainActivity options menu to second Activity Error/Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am having a difficult time understanding this error.  I have an inent that starts in the Main_Activitie option menu.
I am getting this error in my LogCat:
07-07 20:09:40.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 20:09:40.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.TS.3000/com.TS.3000.AddRestaurantActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException
When I debug there says there is NPE and No Source Found Window comes up.  I've tried add new source folders but not change in error.   Here is the section in my main activity that is calling the intent:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // this handles when user selects add button
    Intent addRestaurant = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            AddRestaurantActivity.class);
    Log.i("First", "Log.v");
    startActivity(addRestaurant);
    Log.i("Second", "Log.v");
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

********AddRestaurantActivity*************** second activity being called

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_restaurant);
    Log.i("fourth", "Log.v");
    restName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtT_rest_name);
    restStreet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtT_restaurant_street_address);
    restCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtT_restaurant_city_address);
    phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtT_restaurant_phone);

    Button saveRestaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_saveRestaurant);
    saveRestaurant.setOnClickListener(saveRestaurantButtonClicked);
}

OnClickListener saveRestaurantButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() {
    String restaurantName = restName.getText().toString();
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (restName.getText().length() != 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddRestaurantActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("restName", restaurantName);
            startActivity(intent);
        Log.i("fifth", "Log.v");
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    AddRestaurantActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null);
            builder.show();
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the XML where I added the intent:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AddRestaurantActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I comment out my OnClickListner the intent from the MainActivity to the AddRestaurantActivity operates fine.

I'm not sure if the problem is in declaring my intent in the manifest for the AddRestaurantActivity, or needing to add a source to android.jar. I'm new to android and debugging this problem is difficult. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are Main Activity and AddRestaurantActivity in the same package? You could try to change android:name=".AddRestaurantActivity" to full package name, like android:name="com.myapplication.activity.AddRestaurantActivity".

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and it didn't change the results. Thanks for the response

Comment: I figured this one out.  I didn't declare an onActivityResult back in the main activity.  I didn't think that should have cause the problem, but when I added to the main activity all worked well.